# Accessing members of generic value types in C#

Tags: c#, generics, coordinate-systems

I am writing a C# program that does calculations in several coordinate systems, and transforms between them.  To prevent mix-ups I would like to use a separate, static, value-type for each kind of coordinate.  eg:

```
struct FooSpaceCoords {
    double x, y, z;
}

struct BarSpaceCoords {
    double x, y, z;
}
```

Now a convenient and type-safe matrix class would be nice.  But the following cannot work:

```
 public class MatrixTransform<To, From> where To : struct, From : struct 
 {
    .... some implementation that requires .x, .y and .z ....
 }
```

This fails because compiler can't know that `To` and `From` have members `.x`, `.y` & `.z`.

I could define an `IHaveXYZ` interface, but it seems to me that that will result in a lot of boxing operations which defies the spirit of the whole plan (and is less effecient, if that matters).

Is there an easy way to do what I originally wanted?

Comment: There is no boxing performed when you have an interface constraint and use it's member within generic class methods.

Comment: So the interface constraint is a kind of "language" for explaining what is inside the type, and not an instruction to actually use an interface pointer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I could define an IHaveXYZ interface, but it seems to me that that will result in a lot of boxing operations which defies the spirit of the whole plan (and is less effecient, if that matters).

No, it won't - if you use a generic type constraint, the generated IL will *not* box/unbox. For example:

```
interface IFoo
{
    void Foo();
}

struct Bar : IFoo
{
    public void Foo()
    {
        // Do something
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void DoFoo<T>(T value) where T : IFoo
    {
        value.Foo();
    }

    static void Main()
    {
        Bar bar = new Bar();
        DoFoo(bar); // No boxing involved
    }
}
```

The IL for `DoFoo` looks like this:

```
.method private hidebysig static void  DoFoo<(IFoo) T>(!!T 'value') cil managed
{
  // Code size       16 (0x10)
  .maxstack  8
  IL_0000:  nop
  IL_0001:  ldarga.s   'value'
  IL_0003:  constrained. !!T
  IL_0009:  callvirt   instance void IFoo::Foo()
  IL_000e:  nop
  IL_000f:  ret
} // end of method Test::DoFoo
```

Note the "constrained" part. From ECMA-335 section I.8.2.4:

> Boxing and unboxing of generic arguments adds performance overhead to a CLI implementation. The `constrained.` prefix can improve performance during virtual dispatch to a method defined by a value type, by avoiding boxing the value type.

It's important that you *don't* just refer to `value` as `IFoo` though. This line *would* box the value (when `T` is a value type):

```
IFoo copy = value; // Might box
```

So long as you stick to the generic type parameter, you should be okay.

Comment: Good then.  I will do it that way.  But as an academic question will the compiler generate multiple, identical implementations.  (It doesn't matter in this case, it's not like I have 1000 different coordinate systems).

Comment: @AdrianRatnapala: The JIT compiler will use one native implementation when `T` is a reference type, and a separate native implementation for each value type.

Comment: @JonSkeet I'll do a little off-topic here: could you recommend any sources about JIT and how it works deep down? It's really interesting how generic class is differently resolved by JIT when T is reference/value type.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek I am guessing here, but I assume that for ref types, the JIT uses actual method calls into whatever vtable is normally used for `IFoo`.  That's the neat thing about using Interfaces as the common language.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek: I don't know of any really good resources, to be honest. I've picked things up from lots of articles over the years.

Answer (score 1):

Implement a common interface for both structs and change fields to properties.

```
interface ISomething
{
    Double X{ get;}
    Double Y{ get;}
    Double Z{ get;}
}
```

then add this interface as generic constraint. You're done

Note: as @Jon pointed generic constraints wont box the valuetypes.